# Cannot create foreign key constraint on self-joining Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: ef-core-2.0

I have created the following classes:

```
public class Character
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Relationship> RelatedTo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Relationship> RelatedFrom { get; set; }
}

public class Relationship
{
    public int ToID { get; set; }
    public int FromID { get; set; }

    public Character CharacterFrom { get; set; }
    public Character CharacterTo { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

In my Context I have this:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
            .HasKey(r => new { r.ToID, r.FromID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
            .HasOne(r => r.CharacterFrom)
            .WithMany(r => r.RelatedTo)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.FromID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
            .HasOne(r => r.CharacterTo)
            .WithMany(r => r.RelatedFrom)
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ToID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull);
    }
```

I *think* that it is right but I cannot apply the migration due to the following error:

```
Cannot create the foreign key "FK_Relationship_Character_FromID" with the SET NULL referential action, because one or more referencing columns are not nullable.
```

I've tried every combination of **DeleteBehaviour** for OnDelete. None of them work. I don't believe I can make the ICollections nullable and it doesn't seem right that I'd want to. I've spent two hours on this searching for answers. Every tutorial or explanation on EF Core that I've tried to follow seems to take a slightly different approach and be subtly incompatible with every other one. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you cannot use `DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull` (or `DeleteBehavior.SetNull`) because the corresponding FK property is not nullable - both `ToID` and `FromID` are of type `int`, hence does not allow *setting to `null`* (neither client nor server).

To turn off the cascade delete (in order to break the multiple cascade paths I guess) for *required* FK relationships, use `DeleteBehavior.Restrict` instead.

Comment: I had tried DeleteBehaviour.Restrict several times and it still threw a similar error which is what confused me. However, I've now deleted all migrations and the database and started again from scratch and THIS time, it has worked. Seems I simply needed to remove failed migrations before making changes! V. frustrating, but thank you.